# How to remove Space from the beginning of a File Name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have used these codes but none of them worked:

```
get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace('^ ', "") }

get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace('^[[:space:]]', "") }

get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace('^[" "]', "") }

get-childitem *.mp3 | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace('^\s', "") }
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Propose that as an Answer rather than just a comment. Include an example of the usage.

Answer (score 3):

As commenter [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) correctly wrote, the [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) method does not support RegEx.

The clearest way to remove **any sequence** of whitespace from the start is [`String.TrimStart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-6.0):

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.TrimStart() }
```

If you actually want to remove only a **single** whitespace character from the start, you could use RegEx through the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator:

```
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^\s' }
```

**Unrelated improvement:**

I have removed `ForEach-Object` (alias `foreach`). The `-Path` parameter can be fed directly from the pipeline. The argument for `-NewName` can be a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), because the parameter also accepts pipeline input.